# Options to avoid the GameOver function in a game

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I'm working on a game using xcode and I want to create a super item (like the star in Super Mario) If you touch this super item, you can pass all the obstacles without lose (avoid the game over). But really I don't have an good idea to do this.

I have my current gameover function in my game, If I touch the obstacle area, I die. Obstacles are UIView Objects. If the player touch any obstacle:
`[self gameover];`

I can try two things: First, I can make the image invisible, But If I use:

player.hidden = YES;

when the player touch some obstacle, the player dies (game over). Obviously is hidden but the object is still there. I need an option to set player invisible to all the obstacles in the game.

Second: I can avoid the gameover if the player is using an special item.
This is what I'm try to do:

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(player.frame, superitem.frame)) {
    [avoid gameover];
```

I really don't know the correct function to do this. Hope to receive some help. Thanks

Comment: Please add more detail to this question, like tags for the environment you're working in, language, etc.

Comment: What's the problem? Can you simply skip the collision check if you're in "super" mode?

Comment: Why don't you remove the obstacle instead of just setting it to hidden? Another option is to subclass `UIView` to add a `collisionsEnabled` property and set it to `NO`.

Comment: Jacob: Im working with XCODE

Comment: Greg Hewgill: Your idea sound GREAT, That's exactly what I need, but How to do this?

Comment: Guy Kogus: I'm working with Xcode, I never hear about this property on UIView, can you please post a simple code using this property? Thanks

Comment: It doesn't matter what IDE your using, your still developing in Objective-C.  Guy is suggesting that you _subclass_ UIView in your own custom class, and add a "collisionsEnabled" property to it.  This would allow you to enable and disable collisions on your views when you hit this "special super item"

Comment: Hi Walker Christie: I try to set the CollisionsEnable property on a custom UIView, but I don't see this property as an option.

Comment: *** UPDATE *** Guys, I finally found the correct code to do what I need. I want to share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the correct code to do what I need. I want to share it, maybe someone need to do this and this code can help.

```
UIImageView* tempf = [coins];
if (tempf.tag == obstacles)
{ 
[coins removeObject:tempf];
[tempf removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Thanks everyone's for your help.